# SQL Server : Casting a decimal value to nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column with datatype `decimal(3,0) null`

Column has values like `80, 90, 100`

To this decimal value column, I need to append an % sign.

I need to cast the `decimal` value to `nvarchar`.

Expected output is `80%, 90%, 100%`

Comment: It must do your presentation/reporting layer.

Comment: ididnt get that ? anyway to cast it from sql syntax itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(YourColumn AS VARCHAR(3)) + '%' 
FROM YourTable
```